# Panel with autoscroll, and inner panel that is large. Resizes huge. C#

Tags: c#, winforms, layout

I have a Panel where I am editing some boxes in that is 4000 x 4000 in size.
I put it in a Panel with scroll bars set to auto.
If I make the outer panel not resizable then I get the scroll bars fine.
If I make the out panel resizable so I can resize the window and have it grow and shrink, then the outer panel grows to 4k x 4k and the window is huge and won't let me resize the window.

How does one make a large canvas scrollable in a outer scroll panel such that the outer panel resizes to take up extra space but does not make the outer window resize huge?

[image: This is the outer Win Form and the middle lower area is the auto-scroll panel.]

[image: This is the inner big edit area Panel.]

Comment: I can't reproduce.

Comment: If by _resizable_ you mean setting the outer panel's [AutoSize Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/autosize-property-overview) to true, then that is problem.  Set the outer panel's [Anchor Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.anchor?view=netframework-4.8) to `Top, Bottom, Left, Right` instead or use its [Dock Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.dock?view=netframework-4.8) to align its edges with its parent control.

Comment: Ok got it.  You set the outermost Frame to not autosize, the scroll panel to auto size.

Comment: Update: The Outermost Window Frame must not be autosize.  Then the outermost panel in the frame must be autosize and NOT a flow layout.  Use just Panel so no child component positioning gets done.  Set the outer Panel to Fill. Then position the top UI bar and the lower scroll panel. The lower scroll panel must be autosize as is the top bar, but the top bar has the minimum and maximum height set, and the width set to 0. Then the innermost huge panel is set fixed size (4k x 4k) and it scrolls fine.